# About the gravity field around a lightbeam

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, spacetime, curvature

Imagine there is an infinitely long beam of light. It has impulse and energy. How it affects the spacetime surrounding it? Will masses be pulled towards it perpendiculary and pulled in the parallel direction of the beam's momentum? Will another light-beam be pulled to it and bent, where the bending depends on the orientation of the beams? It seems obvious that if the beams are parallel and the momenta have the same direction, there is no bending but approaching only (there is no frame-dragging in that case, contrary to the momenta being opposite).